# trying to login and register with parse.com

Tags: javascript, web, parse-platform

I did a sample to login and signup to parse.com and i was working , then i retry to login and signup the error is:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
signin.html:56 login error:invalid session token

My Signin Code:

```
Parse.initialize("I removed the keys here");

var item = Parse.Object.extend("User");

$("#signin-submit").click(function(event){

 event.preventDefault();

var username = $("#signin-username").val();
var password = $("#signin-password").val();

Parse.User.logIn(username,password, {error: function(user,error){
   console.log("login error:"+error.message);
}
 });

});

$("#fb").click(function(event){
  Parse.User.logOut();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var myApp = angular.module('signinPage',[]);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}])
```

;

My signup Code:

```
 Parse.initialize("I removed the keys");

 var item = Parse.Object.extend("User");

 $("#signup-submit").click(function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

  var first = $("#signup-name").val();
  var last = $("#signup-family").val();
  var username = $("#signup-username").val();
  var email = $("#signup-email").val();
  var password = $("#signup-password").val();
  var country = $("#signup-country").val();

  var newUser = new item();

  newUser.set("first",first);
  newUser.set("last",last);
  newUser.set("username",username);
  newUser.set("email",email);
  newUser.set("password",password);
  newUser.set("country",country);

  newUser.save(null,{success:function(){
     console.log('youre signed up');
  }, error: function(user , error){
     console.log("signup eroor:"+error.message);
  }});



 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are using save method to register a user instead of signUp method ?? From Parse documentation:

> Note that we used the signUp method, not the save method. New Parse.Users should always be created using the signUp method. Subsequent updates to a user can be done by calling save.